# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'img1')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I m on react.js

```
async function Banners(props) {
  const response = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}/assets/get`);

  return (
    <MainContent
      text={response.text}
      img1={props.img1 ? props.img1 : response.data.img1}
      img2={props.img2 ? props.img2 : response.data.img2}
    />
  );
}
```

the error is only occuring when there is "async"

Comment: You can create a function which will be `async` and call api in there. error is saying everything. you are trying to access `img1` property of `undefined`.

Comment: You will need to wrap that async API call in an useEffect Hook and store the response in a state and render that or pass that to child components etc.

Comment: @DecPK when I console.log it, it has the correct output it should have

Comment: @konekoya Thanks, can you post that as an answer so I can mark it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the async API call in a useEffect Hook and store the data in a state so the state can be used in the render function. Here is an example code without testing:

```
function Banners(props) {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}/assets/get`);
    setResponse(response);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <MainContent
      text={response.text}
      img1={props.img1 ? props.img1 : response.data.img1}
      img2={props.img2 ? props.img2 : response.data.img2}
    />
  );
}
```